# Fix python terminal not showing output

Tags: python, graphics

When I run the main or eqparse file, the python terminal will not show any output. This applies to both the command prompt and visual studio code.

Here is my code from the main file. I am including some of the likely unrelated stuff just in case. It is labeled so you can skip all the potentially unrelated stuff.

```
from graphics import *
from eqparse import *
# NOTE: For equation mapping, it will input a string and convert the data to a table. 
# After, you take in the table coords and map each point 


# dump vars here #
xypm = 0
global patternFind
global count
global indexlist
# profile initialization #
def init(name, nxsize, nysize, noffset, nzoom):
    global zoom
    zoom = nzoom
    global xsize
    xsize = nxsize
    global eqtype
    eqtype = bool(1)
    global ysize
    ysize = nysize
    global win
    win = GraphWin(name, nxsize, nysize)
    global offset
    offset = noffset
    global xymark
    xymark = (nzoom * -1)/2 
    global txsize
    txsize = nxsize/2
    global tysize
    tysize = nysize/2
    global txymark
    txymark = xymark * -1 + 1
    global xp1
    xp1 = Point(xypm,(txsize) + offset)
    global yp1
    yp1 = Point((tysize) + offset, xypm)
    global xp2
    xp2 = Point(xypm,(txsize) - offset)
    global yp2
    yp2 = Point((tysize) - offset, xypm)

# starting procedure #
def startUp():
        # xy lines #
    global xymark
    global xp1
    global xp2
    global yp1
    global yp2
    global xypm
    xtrace = Line(Point(0,tysize), Point(xsize,tysize))
    ytrace = Line(Point(txsize,0), Point(txsize,ysize))
    xtrace.draw(win)
    ytrace.draw(win)

        # grid drawer #
    while xymark < txymark:
        
        txline = Line(xp1, xp2)
        tyline = Line(yp1, yp2)
        txline.draw(win)
        tyline.draw(win)
        xypm = xypm + xsize/zoom
        xp1 = Point(xypm,(tysize) + offset)
        yp1 = Point((txsize) + offset, xypm)
        xp2 = Point(xypm,(tysize) - offset)
        yp2 = Point((txsize) - offset, xypm)
        xymark = xymark + 1

        # code for ending mark #
    Line(Point(txsize - offset, ysize - 1), Point(txsize + offset, ysize - 1)).draw(win)
    Line(Point(xsize - 1,tysize - offset), Point(xsize - 1, tysize + offset)).draw(win)

# point drawing #
def drawCo(nx, ny):
    pCircle = Circle(Point(xsize/zoom * (nx) + xsize/2, ysize - (ysize/zoom * (ny) + ysize/2)), 3)
    pCircle.setFill("black")
    pCircle.draw(win)


# main #

print("Checkpoint 1")
init("test",500, 500, 10, 20)
print("Checkpoint 2")
startUp()
print("Checkpoint 3")
drawCo(3,5)
print("Checkpoint 4")
patternFind("Dung","DungBeatlesbeingadungbeetle")
print("Checkpoint 5")
print(count)
print("Checkpoint 6")
for x in range(len(indexlist)):
    print(indexlist[x])
print("Checkpoint 7")



# exit function #
win.getMouse()
win.close()
```

and the eqparse file:

```
#   eqparse will look for certain patterns in strings, generate an equation,
#   and create a table that a drawing function can read


from main import *

global indexlist

global count

global patternFind

global convStr

# convert string to valid equation data


def convStr(input):
    if input[0] == 'y':
        print("Linear")
        
    elif input[0] == 'r':
        print("Polar")
    else:
        print("Use Equation type on left side")

# subroutine that will be used to find patterns in a sequence #

def patternFind(pattern, input):
    indexlist = []
    count = 0
    l = len(pattern)
    tstr =""
    if l > len(input):
        pass
    else:
        i = 0
        j = len(input) - len(pattern) + 1
        k=0
        while j > 0:
            tstr = ""
            i=0
            while len(tstr) < l:
                tstr = tstr + input[i + k]
                i = i + 1
            if tstr == pattern:
                count = count + 1
                indexlist.append(i+k)
            else: 
                continue
            j = j - 1
            k=k+1
```

The output when I run main:

```
Checkpoint 1
Checkpoint 2
Checkpoint 3
Checkpoint 4

(also the window that I run lags out)
```

On a related note: When I use the standard import syntax nothing happens. I have to use from (file) import * for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Yor problem is in `def patternFind()`

in Your second while loop your counter `k` and `j` is never increasing.
So you have a infinite loop.

your code never go beyond the `continue` statement and stuck there forever.

But maybe you can replace that whole function with a python built-in:

```
def patternFind(pattern, input):
    return pattern in input        #true if pattern is in the input
```